# xcode 4 download not completing properly

Tags: imac, data-transfer, xcode

Yesterday I started downloading Xcode 4 to my iMac. It's a very large file, around 4 GB. The next day I found that only 2 GB of it is downloaded and the download had stopped. Before leaving my computer to download, I disabled the automatic sleep setting. Why did it stop? The computer was still on in the morning, and there was no power failure. Is there any way to find what happened?

Comment: Same thing happened to me when I downloaded Xcode 4. After 2GB+ it stopped downloading. I had to do it allover. The second try did work though. I think it has something to do with the Apple server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the server timed out. Just try downloading it again. If you got it through the Mac App Store you can see it and all your purchases under the Purchases tab at the top next to Updates.

Comment: i were downloading it with the developers license.ok....will try again

Comment: @sujith1406 and be ready for another 4gb download for any **update**... That's just how it works.